# Apply CSS style to part of a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to apply a specifc cursor png to only part of a canvas. I have this, which works fine for the whole canvas

```
.myClass {
    cursor: url('../img/myCursor.png') 7 33, auto; /* img hotspot centred*/
}
```

But I'd like, for example, to apply it to only the left hand 50% of canvas (or say first 300px on x axis).

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can position 2 divs over the canvas and have a different `cursor` property for each one:

```js
const c = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(200, 0);
c.lineTo(200, 400);
c.stroke();

/* draw vertical line down middle */
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

#left {
  left: 0;
  cursor: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1') 7 33, auto;
}

#right {
  cursor: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176') 7 33, auto;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas height="400" width="400"></canvas>
  <div class="positioned" id="left"></div>
  <div class="positioned" id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could make it with only one div (let the canvas handle the second state). However, one BIG downside of this method which should probably be acknowledged in this answer is that this will block mouse event listeners added on the canvas directly. One would have to move the listeners (if any) to a common parent.